# Postgres convert long to wide format

Tags: postgresql, pivot, crosstab

Apologies if this question has been answered before, feel free to point it to me, but I can't find a basic, clean answer for (what I feel like should be) a relatively basic question.

I want to convert a postgres table from long to wide format.

Imagine I have a table...

| date | value | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 100 | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | 200 | 1 |
| 2022-01-03 | 300 | 1 |
| 2022-01-01 | 100 | 2 |
| 2022-01-02 | 200 | 2 |
| 2022-01-03 | 300 | 2 |
| 2022-01-01 | 100 | 3 |
| 2022-01-02 | 200 | 3 |
| 2022-01-03 | 300 | 3 |

And I want to output it as...

| date | id_1_value | id_2_value | id_3_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| 2022-01-02 | 200 | 200 | 200 |
| 2022-01-03 | 300 | 300 | 300 |

If you're going to answer though, I want to make it very clear that the way in which you convert the ids to columns needs to be dynamic. For example, if I am doing this to a table with 100 different ids that I do not know before hand, the solution should be able to elegantly handle this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe is to PIVOT as table. While this can be done in SQL it is tedious and error prone and requires *a priori* knowledge of the resulting columns. You need to rewrite the query if data value is added (ie add id 4 to your table). The following is an example.

```
with test_data ( dt, val, id) as 
     (values (date '2022-01-01', 100, 1)
           , (date '2022-01-02', 200, 1)
           , (date '2022-01-03', 300, 1)
           , (date '2022-01-01', 100, 2)
           , (date '2022-01-02', 200, 2)
           , (date '2022-01-03', 300, 2)
           , (date '2022-01-01', 100, 3)
           , (date '2022-01-02', 200, 3)
           , (date '2022-01-03', 300, 3)
     )
-- your query begins here
select dt, max(id_1_value), max(id_2_value), max(id_3_value)
  from ( 
         select dt 
              , case when id = 1 then val else null end id_1_value
              , case when id = 2 then val else null end id_2_value
              , case when id = 3 then val else null end id_3_value
           from test_data
       ) sq 
 group by dt
 order by dt;
```

As a alternative, you may want to investigate the [crosstab](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html) function.  

While SQL is capable of creating a PIVOT it is not designed for it. This is still best left to you application presentation manager;

Comment: Interesting, I thought this would be a more "available" function because the python pandas library has a `pivot` function that does this, but I guess not... thank you very much for this clear explanation!